# Application crashed while downloading SVGImage using SDWebImageSVGCoder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I'm using SVG image in my project which is coming from API, as I know there's no direct method to use,load or download SVG image directly into iOS Swift app So I'm using third party library which is SDWebImageSVGCoder. But I'm facing two issues, First app is crashing while download specific image and second it's written in Objective-C. I'm not good in Objective-C so I tried alot to understand about the issue and I also tried some other libraries but they also not helping. I need help because I'm stuck there and app is crashing everytime and I have no clue. Thanks

Here's my code

```
import SDWebImageSVGCoder

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let SVGCoder = SDImageSVGCoder.shared
        SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(SVGCoder)
        return true
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImageSVGCoder

struct Bank:Decodable {
    var icon: String?
    var name: String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var banks: [Bank] = [Bank(icon: "https://identity.moneyhub.co.uk/bank-icons/virgin", name: "Virgin Money")]
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableView()
    }
    
    func setupTableView() {
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }


}

//MARK: - TABLEVIEW DELEGATE DATASOURCE
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return banks.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: BankTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! BankTableViewCell
        cell.configure(self.banks[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 62
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }
    
}


class BankTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bankNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bankLogoImageView: UIImageView!
    
    class var identifier: String {
        return "BankTableViewCell"
    }
    
    func configure(_ bank: Bank) {
        self.bankNameLabel.text = bank.name
        guard let url = URL(string: bank.icon ?? "") else {return}
        bankLogoImageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
        bankLogoImageView.sd_setImage(with: url)
    }
    
}
```

I want to find out why this library is crashing I posted question on pod Github but they're not responding. Kindly give me any suggestion, solution or alternative library which I can use and solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: is there a crash log when this happens?

Comment: didn't get any crash log just "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x289eb42a02c0)" get this on AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an outdated library that is not supported anymore. To resolve the crash you will need to use SDWebImageSVGNativeCoder. It can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSVGNativeCoder

Comment: I used your recommended Pod it's working in this particular case bus not rendered another images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a crash when trying this url: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/76/Denver_Nuggets.svg

`let svgImage = SVGKImage(contentsOf: svgUrl)`

Here's the crash log. I don't have a solution for this [image]